# Can I force my monitor to fake a higher refresh rate in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, refresh-rate

Here's the skinny: I have two monitors hooked up to my desktop.  My left monitor is 60hz, my right monitor is 144hz.  In order to have a better splitscreen experience when I play games with my roommate, I use NVIDIA surround to make my display double-wide, so that when I use horizontal splitscreen each player has their own screen.  When I enable NVIDIA surround, it forces me to use the lower of the two refresh rates for both monitors, which means my 144hz monitor is stuck at 60hz.

Is there any way for my to trick Windows 10 into believing that my 60hz monitor actually runs at 144hz?  I understand that this wouldn't improve the refresh rate of the 60hz monitor, but it would allow me to run my 144hz monitor at 144hz.

To be honest, the reason I'm doing this is because I learned to play Rocket League at 144hz and playing at 60hz feels like I'm slogging through pudding.

TL;DR: Can I trick Windows 10 into thinking my monitor's refresh rate is higher than it actually is?

Comment: Even if you did trick it, it wouldn't actually run at 144 Hz, you do realize that right?  Wouldn't it be easier just to upgrade your monitor?

Comment: I'm fully aware.  The reason I want to trick it is because I want one monitor to be able to run at 144hz.  My roommate can play at 60hz on the left monitor, but I want to still be able to run it at 144hz on the right monitor, as this is how I've learned to play the game.

Comment: That's my point; your 144 hz monitor will still be running at 60 Hz based on the way the program must be programmed.